# constraints on tensorflow variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to define a trainable variable **A** in tensorflow with shape [2,3]

A= [ [a1,a2,a3] , [b1,b2,b3] ], such that:
 a1 < a2 < a3 and b1 < b2 < b3

How to impose such constraint in tensorflow

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: (No TF-user): and what would be used to train that? Most optimizers are *unconstrained continuous opt* only (SG and co.; constrained-opt as unconstrained-opt is sometimes doable but model-dependent and no tool will do that for you probably). For everything else you might checkout tensorflow's scipy.optimize wrapper (not sure if that wrapper is supporting constraints; but scipy's slsqp does).

Answer (score 0):

Slice a2 (and respectively b2) and use https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value with a1 and a3 (respectively b1 and b3) as your lower and upper bounds.

Comment: but one case of your solution is going to be either a2=a1 or a2 =a3

Comment: Then instead of using a1 and a3, use a1 + SMALL and a3 - SMALL where SMALL could be 1e-10.

Comment: but what if the variable with shape [100,10000] do you think the solution will work

Comment: Can you clarify how your constraints apply in that scenario?

Comment: Out of curiousity: what's the underlying optimization-theory behind that approach? As a tf-layman, this looks pretty non-smooth (and probably is not an euclidean-projection as in common projected gradient descent approaches).

Comment: @sascha this is not really applying constraints on optimization but rather clipping the value to lower or upper bound if it falls outside of the interval after each gradient descent step taken. Note that, this may or may not satisfy OP's problem.


Abrar, you can use a for loop to easily generalize the same idea for the [100, 10000] case.

Comment: @sascha what I want is that the value of a1 is always smaller than a2 and a2 is smaller than a3, and I am not sure if clip by value will a achieve this.

Comment: Clip will achieve what you have described by its definition. Am I missing something?

Comment: I will try it and let you know, what I need to do is to slice the matrix without the for loop and then i will try the clip op.